# Scala: indexOf returns -1 despite me appending an item right before that

Tags: arrays, scala, append, indexof

I have a class like this:

```
case class TrendsByTicker(var tickers: Array[String], var trends: Array[Array[YearlyTrend]])
```

and initially I have a var like this:

```
var zeroVal = TrendsByTicker(Array[String](), Array(Array[YearlyTrend]()))
```

which I pass as the `acc` argument of this function:

```
def seqOp(acc: TrendsByTicker, value: Stock): TrendsByTicker = {

    if (!acc.tickers.contains(value.ticker)) {
      acc.tickers :+ value.ticker
      acc.trends :+ initializedTrends
    }

    val index = acc.tickers.indexOf(value.ticker)


    //do something else
}
```

Where `value.ticker` is a String.
As you can see I want to check if `value.ticker` is contained by the `acc.tickers` String Array and if it's not, append it. Finally then get the index of `value.ticker` which I just put.
I don't understand why by indexOf returns me -1 even though I just did an append.
I know that the string in `value.ticker` if that's something you need to know.
What's going on? Why can't indexOf find the `value.ticker` I just appended?

Comment: Even if you are using mutable references and mutable data structures all the way, you are not mutating the values. `acc.tickers :+ value.ticker` this lien returns a new array. - BTW, all that mutability is usually discouraged.

Comment: Thank you. And I'll try to tone down the mutability.